# Difference between [:,3] and [:,3:4] in python?

Tags: python, pandas

After importing dataset I see the different size of objects created by iloc when provided similar parameters.

I was trying to create a simple linear regression model.

```
y=dataset.iloc[:,3].values
z=dataset.iloc[:,3:4].values
```

I expected y and z to be same but in variable explorer, size of y is (10,) and z is (10,1).
How do y and z get differentiated?

Comment: What does the *question* have to do with Machine Learning?  What relevant modules are you using that you have not identified?

Comment: Same as the difference between `a[1]` and `a[1:2]`?

Comment: This is the same as `lst = ['a','b','c']` then `lst[2]` vs `lst[2:3]`

Comment: `:,3` is `(slice(None, None, None), 3)`, while `:,3:4` is `(slice(None, None, None), slice(3, 4, None))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because when you put a single number it means a row or a column. However, if you put as `a:b`, it assumes it as a range, even if the number of elements is 1.